# setting size as n in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, strlen

I've studied programming C courses at university for about 4 months.

In C, it's a kind of "rule" to always set a size (length) of something equal to n in the for loop. I'll show in the example beneath.

```
for(int i = 0, n = strlen(x); i < n; i++) {
```

In java however, I never see someone setting the length/size of an arraylist/character sequence/etc. equal to n and THEN having the condition. 
We would always get 1 point less or something like that if we consistently didn't do such things. It is better, because the computer doesn't have to search for the length over and over (every time it iterates).

Why don't people use this in java? Is there a reason for that? Doesn't it matter enough to do it?

**Edit:** I've seen that neither much people do this in C.. Anyway, I've learnt it like this and I'm consistently doing this in Java too.

Comment: In java you still have to set the n to whatever length you want it to be, it is just not part of the for loop syntax, so you have it set if before the for loop

Comment: No, setting it like for(int i = 0, n = arrayList.size(); i <n; i++) { would create the variable and it wouldnt be made every time it iterates.

Comment: Initializing `n` in this case expresses a contract that the value of `n` should not be changed, but does not really enforce that contract. If you wanted the length to be constant, defining `final String x = "foo";` would be more appropriate. In addition, there are plenty of reasons you would modify a list's contents of some sort on the fly, for example if you wanted to remove duplicates, where this would result in an ArrayOutOfBounds exception. I'm not completely familiar with JLS, but I would assume that repeated calls to `size` methods would optimize to return the same value.

Comment: "contract that the value of n should not be changed, but does not really enforce that contract." Isn't that better? Wouldn't you recommend using n = size then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of code optimization. Higher-level languages' compilers will automatically add this optimization and others like it. I am not familiar enough about C compilation to say whether they typically add this optimization automatically. I recommend researching the specific compiler you were using to find out if that's the case.

It would have been a kindness of your professor to note why this approach was so important to him. I can tell you that it is not idiomatic of languages such as Java, and makes your code less readable, so I'd recommend against this practice unless you can demonstrate a clear benefit. He was probably trying to train you to do this by default because some lower-level languages won't handle this automatically, and getting the count could be expensive, if you say needed to get the count from an API or database for some reason.

Edit: Compass in the comments makes an excellent point. If you're in the habit of modifying the list you're in inside the body of your loop, you're gonna have a bad time if you don't assign the loop terminator ahead of time. It's usually just not a good idea to modify the size of a list inside a loop that depends on that list anyway though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And yep, he just said that it was because it wouldnt have to also search for the length of something. It might be code optimization, but how much would it matter if we talk about a game like GTA 5? Where there are many for loops. Maybe it does, I don't know honestly. Maybe the compiler does it, I've no idea. Only thing that I know is that it doesn't seem to matter in Java as I'm reading about 100 thousand of lines in multiple for loops and even WITH plenty of calculations, hashmaps and arraylists and much more, it takes about 1 second..

Comment: If you really want to know what the compiler does, you could look up a Java decompiler and see what the compiler produced! It probably will look very different than what you wrote. You could always attach a stopwatch to a toy app and run a big loop about 10000 times to see how long each version takes!

Comment: Oo interesting idea. I think I should investigate this further haha. But ye, maybe the professor is a bit too oldschool when compilers didnt do all that stuff for you?

Comment: Ultimately, don't worry about this kind of optimization unless you have *proof* that that's where your performance bottlenecks are. In my experience, the biggest drains on performance are larger things like making more API calls than necessary, N+1 issues in DB transactions, pulling records without limit, etc...

Comment: Yes it's unbelievable how fast everything's these days. I really don't get it sometimes.. But besides that, I just find it interesting to know more about the theory etc. you know? I love to learn about every single aspect.

Comment: Optimization is done at runtime by the JIT compiler. The code shouldn't look very different if you just decompile it.

Comment: But.. We all agree on the fact that if n = size in the forloop, it doesn't try to set the variable n equal to the size every time it iterates?

Comment: And if we agree on that, what happens when you change the value of n inside of the for loop

Answer (score 2):

In Java you're usually referencing some pre-calculated field like `arr.length`, `str.length()`, `list.size()`. The benefits of storing them in a variable are insignificant and the JIT compiler could probably do it automatically, if it would help. But if you can demonstrate a significant improvement in [some particular case](http://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bugDescriptions.html#iil-nodelist-getlength-called-in-a-loop-iil-elements-get-length-in-loop), by all means go ahead.

Comment: Okay thanks man. Do you know whether it is a different story in C? Cuz I've seen people not using it in C either.. Though my professor always told us to do that otherwise it could have bad impact on grades lol. Must be something behind it right.. I mean i'll use it anyway because im used to it now , but I love to know more about the theory behind it.

Comment: I don't know enough about C standards to say. But I know enough about professors to be skeptical.

Comment: Being sceptical is always a good thing haha, but he's one of the most known C programmers in the world..

Answer (score 0):

Array has length property saved as a `public final field` as said in [10.7 Array Member](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7)

> The `public final field length`, which contains the number of components
>   of the array. length may be positive or zero.

Normal access to object field is via `getfield` instruction but to get the array length, Java provide a special instruction [`arraylength`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.9.arraylength) for it:

> All arrays have associated lengths, which are accessed via the
>   `arraylength` instruction.

So access to `array.length` is direct and no different than an access to local variable